# Navigation bar disappears after background animation

Tags: html, ios, css

I've been working on a website, and we wanted to an animated background. But the problem with this is that my Navbar disappears after the second picture is displayed.

This only happens on iOS devices, because my partner tried it with android and it worked how it is supposed to.

(tried it on both safari and google chrome.)

With header:[image]

header disappears:

[image]

homepage:

```
    <body>
<div class="bg-fade">
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
    <figure></figure>
</div>
<div id="main-container">

<!-- header -->
<?php include('inc/header.php'); ?>
```

CSS BACKGROUND:

```
.bg-fade > figure {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: fixed;
  animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
  background-size: cover;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(1) {
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_01.jpg');
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_02.jpg');
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_03.jpg');
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_04.jpg');
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_05.jpg');
}
.bg-fade > figure:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 30s;
  background-image: url('https://maasduinenpas.nl/img/maasduinenpas_bg_06.jpg');
}

/*keyframes .bg-fade*/
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes imageAnimation {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  }
  17% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

CSS NAV:

```
/*navigation*/
nav ul {
    margin: 37px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 100;
    opacity: 1;
}
nav li.left {
    float: left;
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0px -45px 0px 50px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    background-color: #E6332A;
    position: relative;
}
nav li.left:hover {
    background-color: #ff3333;
}
nav li.left.active {
    background-color: #E6332A;
}
nav li.left.active:after {
    left: 45%;
    width: 0px;
    bottom: -20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid #E6332A;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
nav li.right.navigation-msp {
    color: #ffffff;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #EF7D03;
}
nav li.right.navigation-msp:hover {
    background-color: #F88017;
}
nav li.right.active:after {
    left: 45%;
    width: 0px;
    bottom: -20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 20px solid #EF7D03;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
}
nav li.right.active.navigation-msp:hover {
    background-color: #EF7D03;
}
.handle {
    width: 100%;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px 10px;
    display: none;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #E6332A;
}
.handle:hover {
    background-color: #FF3333;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
nav ul {
    position: relative;
    color: #ffffff;
    margin-top: 37px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
nav li.left {
color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
font-size: 14px;
background-color: #E6332A;
position: relative;
}
nav li.right.navigation-msp {
color: #ffffff;
width: 100%;
margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
display: inline-block;
padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
font-size: 14px;
position: relative;
}
nav a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}
nav ul li {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
    background-color: #E6332A;
}
nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav ul {
    max-height: 0;
}
.showing {
    max-height: 15em;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.handle {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: i have seen this question for this website before, is it still the same problem ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48500124/nav-ul-disappears-because-of-animated-background

Comment: Yes still the same problem i'm really stuck with this

Comment: @Dirk I'm not allowed to? Because no one responds or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: i dont have a problem with you asking multiple times, can you tell me some more about which iOS version an device you have, because i can see the problem on browserstack

Comment: could you try and vendor prefix animation and animation-delay ? i think that is the problem here for older iOS versions

-webkit-animation:imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation:imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
animation:imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;